# a function which does not converge in $L^2$

Tags: measure-theory

Please, help me, with this issue:
Let $f_n:(0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$, $f_n(x)=\frac{n}{1+n\sqrt x}$. I was asked to show that $f_n\in L^2(0,1]$. I have to prove that $$\left( \int_{(0,1]} f_n(x)^2~d\lambda \right)^{\frac{1}{2}}<\infty $$ We have that:
$\int_{(0,1]}f_n(x)^2~d\lambda=n^2 \int_{(0,1]}\frac{1}{1+n^2 x+2n\sqrt{x}}~dx$ ..I dont know how to continue..could it be helpful to majorate that fraction I have to integrate?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, $\lim_{x\to 0+}f_n(x)^2=n^2$ and $\lim_{x\to 1-}f_n(x)^2=\frac{n^2}{(1+n)^2}$. Moreover, $1+n^2x+2n\sqrt{x}=0$ iff $1+n\sqrt{x}=0$, and since $x>0$, then there is no $x\in(0,1]$ such that denominator be 0.

Thus $f_n^2$ is continuos in $=(0,1]$ and can be continously extended to all $[0,1]$. Therefore, it is integrable on $[0,1]$ in Riemman sense, and thus in Lebesgue sense in $(0,1]$ and both integrals are the same.

Indeed the value of the integral is $2 (\frac{1}{n+1}+\log(n+1)-1)$

Comment: So,actually the function does not belong to $L^{2}((0,1]$?

Comment: I understand, it is integrale in Lebesgue sense, but I dont think the function is in $L^{2}((0,1])$.

Comment: Why don't you believe $f_n\notin L^2((0,1])$?

Comment: I obtained the same value of the integral.

Comment: Because my teacher of analysis said it belongs..and it seems it doesnt..

Comment: Mmm we are proving that $f_n\in L^2((0,1])$. Are you agree?

Comment: He sustained that the value of that integral is a real number, without calculating it.

Comment: Yes. The value of the integral is a real number and it can see without calculating (indeed it was my argument). And so?

Comment: Yes, I am.But in order to $f_{n}$ to be in $L^{2}$, that integral must be finite, i,e a real number. And it is not.

Comment: So my teacher is wrong, this is my point..

Comment: Noooo!! Read my answer!! I show that $\int_{(0,1]}f_n^2dx<\infty$!! You are wrong!

Comment: Why do you insist in $f_n\notin L^2?$

Comment: Because we obtained that value.And, if $n$ goes to $\infty$, that value goes to $\infty$ also...:(

Comment: As I see, you are confusing $f_n$, $\int f_n$, $\lim \int f_n$ and $\int \lim f_n$.

Comment: In your OP, you ask for $f_n\in L^2$. It is exactly that i answered to you. There is not limit of any kind.

Comment: And, as $n$ takes values 1,2,3,...,that value obtained is a real number..

Comment: So n is fixed, given.

Comment: Please, read CAREFULLY your original post. I don't know what are you saying. I only know the original post. Any other thought that you have should be in the original post.